# Creating a VAR model - data with seasonalities

Tags: modeling, model, vector-autoregression, seasonality

I am in process of creating a forecast using VAR model for pricing of a certain commodity.
Some of my variables (such as price itself, as well as inflation, and taxation) don't have any seasonalities. At the same time, other variables (export, import, production) have a glaring yearly seasonality.

The question is, can I deal with this issue within the model (such as - adding seasonal dummies when checking the model criteria). Or should I deal with seasonalities beforehand, for example, by using 'seasadj' and then removing the seasonalities just for those variables that have them? What is the intuition in this case?